# Merging 2 tables with first five characters in common

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to merge two tables with the condition that even if the words are not exact same, at least the first 8 characters should be same but not able to do so. My table contains name of customers with first name then last name and then middle name.

In second table, many of them do not have middle name hence I am not able to merge most of the records. Here is the code I am working on:

```
SELECT
UPPER(REGEXP_REPLACE(A.NAME, '\s*', ''))
FROM
TABLE1 A,
TABLE2 B
WHERE
UPPER(REGEXP_REPLACE(A.NAME, '\s*', '')) = UPPER(REGEXP_REPLACE(B.NAME, '\s*', ''))
AND
ORDER BY A.NAME;
```

Edit: (From comments)

I would like to match `RAVI YADAV KUMAR` with `RAVI YADAV K` and other similar records.

Comment: Could you provide some examples of input and your expedted output?

Comment: @Fluffeh It's not SQL Server.

Comment: Sorry folks to add to sql server.  HERE is a sample record "RAVI YADAV KUMAR" In Fisrt table "RAVI YADAV K" in other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT A.NAME,B.NAME
FROM TABLE1 A, TABLE2 B
WHERE UPPER(SUBSTR(A.NAME, 1, 8)) = UPPER(SUBSTR(B.NAME, 1, 8))
ORDER BY A.NAME,B.NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can use `LEFT` on that

```
SELECT A.name,B.name
FROM tableA A INNER JOIN tableB B
       ON LEFT(A.name, 8) = LEFT(B.name, 8)
ORDER BY A.name, B.name
```

question, do the value on every column has 8 characters and above?

Comment: They might be less but mostly more than 8 characters

Answer (score 0):

How about this query:

```
SELECT A.name,B.name
FROM tableA A, tableB B
   WHERE UPPER(SUBSTR(A.name, 0, 8)) = UPPER(SUBSTR(B.name, 0, 8))
ORDER BY A.name, B.name;
```